# Checkbox always passing false even if checked in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-state

I have a checkbox and when it's checked/unchecked, it writes true or false in the console, however, when I try and save the value, it's always passing false.

html:

```
<input type="checkbox" 
       name="Status"
       value="Status"
       onChange={(e) => {carStatus(e)}) />
```

```
const CarState = {
      carId: 0,
      Make: "",
      Model: ""
      Active: ""   //this is a bit in the DB
}

const [carMake, setCarMake] = useState(CarState);
const [carModel, setCarModel] = useState(CarState);
const [carActive, setActive] = useState(CarState);

const carStatus = (e) => {
   const status = e.target.checked;
   if(status)
   {
      console.log("checked " + status);
      setCarActive({ ...carActive, status});
   }
   else
   {  
      console.log("checked" + status);
      setCarActive({ ...carActive, status});
   }

const saveCar = () => {
       var data = {
          make: carMake.CarMake,
          model: carModel.Model,
          active: saleActive.Active  //always false even if checkbox is checked
      };
  
     //passes data to the API

}
```

Is there a better way to do this or a different way? I can see true/false in F12 if the checkbox is checked or not, however, just passes false when I click the save button [saveCar function]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not updating the nested `Active` state, you are adding a `status` property and not referencing it. Use the `checked` value and update the `Active` property in state.

```
const [carActive, setCarActive] = useState(CarState);

...

const carStatus = (e) => {
  const { checked } = e.target;

  console.log("checked " + checked);

  setCarActive(carActive => ({
    ...carActive,    // <-- shallow copy previous state
    Active: checked, // <-- set new Active checked value
  }));
}
```

In the input you should reference the state. Use the `checked` prop/attribute/

```
<input
  type="checkbox" 
  name="Status"
  value="Status"
  checked={carActive.Active} // <-- set the checked prop of input
  onChange={carStatus}
/>
```

In `saveCar` reference the correct state being updated. Ensure all the properties being accessed match the `carState` properties.

```
const saveCar = () => {
  var data = {
    make: carMake.Make,
    model: carModel.Model,
    active: carActive.Active 
  };
  
  //passes data to the API

}
```

### Working Demo

[image: Edit checkbox-always-passing-false-even-if-checked-in-react]

Comment: Still goes through as False,  when I run F12, I can see the true/false if I check/uncheck the checkbox, however, it still saves as false if the checkbox is checked

Comment: the value of the checkbox, so if it's checked, it's being passed as False, if it's not checked still being passed as False to my API call. However, if I run F12, I can see the console.log ("active" + checked) and it says true for checked, false for when I uncheck it

Comment: Yes, I applied your changes and still that checkbox is reading false in the [ saveCar ]  call

Comment: I never used that before, but here it is, let me know if you can see it: https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-fire-mk8se?file=/src/App.js   You can see it showing true/false if the box is checked or not, however, when I go and save it, it shows false on the API call

Comment: still going to the API as false, and I copied your code snippet. I'm going to tear the page down and rebuild it. I can see checked: true, when checked, checked: false, when unchecked, but still goes to the API as false, even if the checkbox is checked. I'm at a loss at the moment on it

Comment: I'm passing my form data to a WebAPI to save the data to my database. I can see the value of the textboxes and if the checkbox was checked or not, all through my code now, up until I get to the .SaveCar() method in the React. That calls my WebAPI Create().

Comment: I got it working, I found a naming issue between the JSON being sent and the what the API was looking for. Once I got that resolved, then the checkbox value was being saved correctly in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
<input 
type="checkbox" 
name="Status"
checked={carActive.Active === true}
onChange={(e) => setActive(state=>({...Active:e.target.checked}))) />
```